# App Hanging on "let SKView as! SKView" (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, xcode6

I am trying to create a SpriteKit based game, and am trying to establish basic bluetooth connectivity before I continue, however my game is crashing while segueing from the menu to the GameScene, and I  am getting a "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SKView'" error. My Game Menu is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

class TitleScreenViewController: UIViewController, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var TitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var PlayLocallyButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var PlayOnlineButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var SettingsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var GameCenterButton: UIButton!
var appDelegate:AppDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PlayLocallyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    PlayLocallyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    PlayLocallyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1

    PlayOnlineButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    PlayOnlineButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    PlayOnlineButton.layer.borderWidth = 1

    SettingsButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    SettingsButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    SettingsButton.layer.borderWidth = 1

    GameCenterButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    GameCenterButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    GameCenterButton.layer.borderWidth = 1

    appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.mpcHandler.setupPeerWithDisplayName(UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    appDelegate.mpcHandler.setupSession()
    appDelegate.mpcHandler.selfAdvertise(true)


}

@IBAction func ConnectWithPlayer(sender: AnyObject) {

    if appDelegate.mpcHandler.session != nil {
        appDelegate.mpcHandler.setupBrowser()
        appDelegate.mpcHandler.browser.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(appDelegate.mpcHandler.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}

func browserViewControllerDidFinish(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController!) {

    appDelegate.mpcHandler.browser.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("OverToGame", sender: self)
}


func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController!) {

    appDelegate.mpcHandler.browser.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

My GameViewController, which the menu segues to and should present the GameScene is as follows. This contains the line where it hangs

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import MultipeerConnectivity

extension SKNode {
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
  }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var appDelegate:AppDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDelegate.mpcHandler.setupPeerWithDisplayName(UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    appDelegate.mpcHandler.setupSession()
    appDelegate.mpcHandler.selfAdvertise(true)

}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    let skView = self.view as! SKView

    if skView.scene == nil {

        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        let gameScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(gameScene)

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Am I even presenting the Scene in the correct fashion?

Comment: When you say 'hangs', what exactly do you mean? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am getting a  "Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SKView'" error.

Comment: I have any idea what the problem **might** be... Did you use the 'Game' template when creating your project?

Comment: I did use the game template.

Comment: Try checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928238/uiview-wont-cast-to-skview

Comment: I'm not too adept when it comes to Objective-C; not really sure what he achieved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `GameViewController` is of class `UIViewController`.  `UIViewController`'s `view` property is of class `UIView`, not `SKView`.

So when you write `let skView = self.view as! SKView` you are saying, hey, I know for sure that my `self.view` is supposed to be of `SKView` type, as indicated by the `as!`.  But it's not, so luckily the compiler stops you before you can run your app and crash it.

`SKView` is the class for the `view` property of `SKScene`

To write games with Sprite Kit you have to know the differences between `UIViewController` and `SKScene`  Good luck!

[SKScene class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/view)

[UIViewController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/)

Comment: Thank you for the references, I definitely need to read up on those. In order to avoid the problem entirely, I just loaded in a backup, and it worked perfectly :/